# how to save login data using NSUserDefaults and checkbox in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, checkbox, nsuserdefaults

hi i am trying to store my username and password in my app with NSUserdefaults and checkbox.
my code is ..

In viewdidload

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:UserText.text  forKey:@"infoString"];
[defaults setObject:PasswdText.text  forKey:@"infoString1"];
[defaults synchronize];
UserText.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"infoString"];
```

and

```
- (IBAction)checkButton:(id)sender {
      if (!checked) {
          [checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_ticked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
          self.UserText.text=[defaults objectForKey:@"infoString"];
          self.PasswdText.text = [defaults objectForKey:@"infoString1"];
          checked = YES;
      }

      else if (checked) {
          [checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_not_ticked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
          checked = NO;
      }
}
```

and my result is if i click checkbox means my textfield is refreshed.where i made mistake?
 thanks in advance.

Comment: is this is a login screen ? and checkbox is "Remember me" ?

Comment: @hemantchittora: yes my checkbox is rememberme and using images in button for checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the values in `NSUserDefaults` when User Performed Submit action, Like this

```
- (void)submitButtontapped {
    if (checked) {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setObject:UserText.text  forKey:@"infoString"];
        [defaults setObject:PasswdText.text  forKey:@"infoString1"];
        [defaults synchronize];
        UserText.text=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"infoString"];
    }
    // do the next thing
}

- (IBAction)checkButton:(id)sender {
    if (checked) {
        checked = NO;
        [checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_not_ticked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        checked = YES;
        [checkBoxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_ticked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```